# Pull Phonegap/Cordova hybrid app www webapp folder remotely for updates

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Is there a way we can pull updates for the web app folder in our hybrid iOS/Android app without taking the pain of releasing a new app each time.

Basically I'm looking for a way to update the "www" folder in my hybrid iOS/android app via some web service (May be we can zip the folder and again unzip it inside our iOS app on successful update).

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer right in stackoverflow:
[Serving cordova app www folder remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26156198/serving-cordova-app-www-folder-remotely)

Also, you can check this out for sample code of Cordova Dynamic Loader:

https://github.com/markmarijnissen/cordova-app-loader